# Can a polygon have four 90 degree corners and still not be a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, polygons, rectangles

On another woodworking forum, someone said that after building a case, you should measure the diagonals to ensure the case is square and that just checking if all the corners are 90 degrees won't suffice. Is it possible for a polygon to have four 90 degree corners and not be a rectangle?  This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Certainly!  It could be a hexagon.

Comment: As MJD correctly points out, mathematically you must first say that the polygon have four sides in order to say that having four 90 degree angles suffice for the polygon to be a rectangle.

Comment: Oddly, there is no such pentagon. This leads to a valuable labor-saving step when building a case. Suppose you have measured 4 angles and found them all to be $90^\circ$, and you want to be sure that what you have  is a rectangle. Now you might think that you next must count the angles and make sure that there are exactly 4, but no! You do *not* have to do this. You can save effort (cutting corners, as it were, ha ha…) because it is sufficient to determine that your polygon has *no more than 5 angles*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that a quadrilateral with four 90 degree corners MUST be a rectangle, in math.  End of story.

In woodworking, however, one must deal with real measurement errors.  It turns out that measuring the diagonals is a more sensitive method of measuring how close to 90 degrees one got, as opposed to measuring the angles with a protractor or other tool.

Comment: Going a bit further, it is actually possible to prove why this is good approach.  The most common way of notating error is with a fixed max error, such as "within 1/8 inch."  Each of the angles can be found with trig, using a ratio.  If you care about the ratio, you find that the longer length you measure, the more accurately you can capture the ratio of the error to the length measured.  This means, if you want to measure an angle, you want to measure with the longest lengths you have available (which matches common sense).  The two longest lengths on an almost-rectangle are the diagonals.

Comment: As an example, let's take a bookcase with angles $89^\circ$ and $91^\circ$ and with a side lengths of $35$ and $75$ inches. It will have diagonals of $\approx 89.209$ and $83.316$ inches. Nearly $6$ inches of difference is easier to see than a degree or two. Like others said the larger the "rectangle" the more apparent this will become, whereas measuring the angles doesn't show more error with size. Even with angles $89.9^\circ$ and $90.1^\circ$ the diagonals are off by over $0.1$ inches. You'd be hard-pressed to find that with a protractor instead of a tape measure.